# wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError) with Expect in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm not getting expect on retrieve method. When I use `expect(@create_user.retrieve.code).to eq (200)`. The following error is displayed:

> wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
>         ./features/pages/Empregados.rb:26:in `retrieve'

```
 def retrieve(id)
  self.class.get("/employee/#{ id }")
end 

    $response = @create_user.create
      expect(@create_user.create.code).to eq (200)
      puts $response.body
      @id = JSON.parse($response)['id']
      puts @create_user.retrieve(@id)
      expect(@create_user.retrieve.code).to eq (200)
][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `retrieve` method takes exactly one param - `id`. In

```
expect(@create_user.retrieve.code).to eq (200)
```

you use `retrieve` without any params, hence the error. Add `id` to the `retrieve` call and it should be OK.

```
expect(@create_user.retrieve(@id).code).to eq (200)
```